# Образование множества из символов

Tags: python, python-3.x, множества

Мне нужно множество, которое будет составляться из 3 элементов: 1) Первые буквы каждого слова из текста заданого с клавиатуры; 2) Буквы, которые повторяются 2 и больше раз; 3) Буквы которые повторяются только 1 раз. В моём коде 3 элемент не прибавляется к множеству отдельным элементом, а смешивается с вторым элементом.

```
text = str(input("text - "))
s = text.split(" ")
b = [i[0] for i in s]
x = "".join(b)
M = set()
twoandmore = []
oneletter = []
M.update([x])
for j in text:
    count = text.count(j)
    if count > 1:
        twoandmore.append(j)
        l = ''.join(set(twoandmore))
        M.update(l)
        M.discard(" ")
    if count == 1:
        oneletter.append(j)
        k = ''.join(set(oneletter))
        M.update(k)
input_set = M
g = list(input_set)
tmp = [i for i in g if len(i) > 1]
res = ''.join([i for i in g if len(i) == 1])
tmp.append(res)
input_set = set(tmp)
print(input_set)
```

Ввод:

```
text - I love spaghetti and birds
```

Вывод:

```
{'Ilsab', 'thsdelgipInbroav'}
```

а нужно

```
{'Ilsab', 'iesatd', 'lovbrnpgh'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
text = 'I love spaghetti and birds'

block1 = ''.join(word[0] for word in text.split())
block2 = ''.join({letter for letter in text.lower() if text.lower().count(letter) > 1 and letter != ' '})
block3 = ''.join({letter for letter in text.lower() if text.lower().count(letter) == 1 and letter != ' '})

res = {block1, block2, block3}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: если есть стандартные средства - лучше всего долбить ими, в моем коде я бы еще сделал `text_l = text.lower().replace(' ', '')` - тогда для 2 и 3 блока меньше кода писать бы пришлось